# Visual Studio 2015 Support for Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, editor, intellisense, visual-studio-2015

As recently claimed by MS that they have added **Reactjs** support in `.JSX` files but I don't get any IntelliSense and on top of that HTML in it gets errors and red squiggly lines in my Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. So, if it is there then how to get it?

Comment: answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32094173/no-intellisense-for-react-in-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably need Web Essentials for 2015

Comment: It was mentioned everywhere that they have implemented in VS2015 itself.