# No intellisense for React in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I don't see any intellisense for ReactJS, for example methods like **React.createClass** although I see **_references.js** file at the root folder. The **_references.js** file has help reference to various react js files.

The extension of my react file is JS and not JSX.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this issue by importing the NuGet package "react.js" and bringing the script locally.

I've also added a `_references.js` to **~/Scripts/** to my project. Visual Studio had a helper under "add..." entitled "**_references.js intellisense file**" which looked like this:

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-2.1.4.js" />
/// <reference path="react/jsxtransformer-0.13.1.js" />
/// <reference path="react/react-0.13.1.js" />
/// <reference path="react/react-with-addons-0.13.1.js" />
```

After that, I was able to use intellisense in my jsx files. The **_references.js** file did not seem to like running from Facebook's CDN.

Comment: I was having some problems with this and it turns out that deleting the .vs/{projname}/v14/.suo file resolved it.

Comment: One more thing, I think the CDN files don't work here because you must go to Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> JavaScript --> Intellisense and check "Download remote references..."

Comment: I have to have nuget plugin just for intellisense, than I have it in node modules folder. Why they can't make intellisense work by checking files in node_modules. It is complicated, not straightforward, seems like lot of hacks are needed to make basic development flow setup. And lot of hacks usually means more potential problems. I came from VS 2013 with no ract support and expected VS2015 support modern frontend developent perfectlly.

Answer (score 1):

**To Fix this issue in Visual Studio concerning the use of React in Visual Studio 2015 Follow the Below Steps**

To resolve this issue we need to configure the **TyScript, WebPack, and IntelliSense** in your project solution.

Steps:

1. Go to the project root folder open CMD and enter the following commands
2. "**`npm install -g webpack`**" (this is for Installing Web-Pack Globally)
3. "**`npm install --save typescript`**" (to install typescript for Application)
4. Create a js file in your solution Named "**webpack.config.js**" and a Config file for typescript named "**tsconfig.json**"
5. Add Following content for //---webpack.config.js

   ```
    module.exports = {
    entry: "./Content/src/food.tsx",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }, 
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx']
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    // Add the loader for .ts files.
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
          }
        ]
    }
   ```

   };

---

6. Add the Following content for //------------tsconfigs -(**Note:** in "include" param in the following JS mention the ts file location. If the ts file is already placed/created in "./Content/src/" then no changes are needed.)

   ```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noResolve": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": false, 
        "jsx": "react"
    },
    "include": [ "./Content/src/**/*" ],
    "exclude": [
    "./plugins/**/*",
    "./typings/**/*",
    "./built/**/*",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot",
    "Scripts/*"
   ```

   ]
   }

//After this Configuration IntelliSense will work but still to make React work we need React-type definitions. To Configure that we need to install React and type script. you have to write the following commands in the root folder of your project.

7. "`tsc -v` or  `NPM view react version`" (this command will help you to **check the version of React**)
8. **if the version is above 2** then run the following commands
   [

   npm install --save react @types/react

   npm install --save react-dom @types/react-dom

   npm install --save typescript awesome-typescript-loader source-map-loader

   npm init

]
9. **If your Intellisencse is not working** then try with the following commands again in your root folder of the project.
[

//run the below command if Intellisense not working

```
 typings install dt~react dt~react-dom -–save

  npm install   
  npm link typescript  

  npm install --save typescript
```

]

10. Try to Build your solution and check whether it succeded or failed - (if it is failing then exclude your tsx file which path you gave in the "include" param of tsconfig.json and Exclude tsconfig.json also.  after this your solution will build successfully but still, your dsx files need to be built using webpack. and webpack you need to execute from the command line by entering the "`webpack`" command in CMD. After which your typescript files will also get compiled and you will be able to use React without errors.)